# Change four divs at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 input fields, with a dropdown element at the end for selecting currency. And what i want to do is when i change on of them, they all change using JS.

For example if i change the second label to USD the other should follow. This is my HTML code for the dropdown on the input fields

```
<div class="ui dropdown label">
  <div class="text">Euro</div>
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">USD</div>
    <div class="item">GBP</div>
    <div class="item">SEK</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would love some pointers how to write the JS function for this. Please no Jquery solutions, just plain JS

Comment: Can you precisely explain your use case?

Comment: In your code there is no dropDowns, only `div`s and `i`

Comment: I wanna be able to put in a starting, ending prices and the user should be able to choose between som diffrent currencies

Comment: I use semantic, so yes, it is a dropdown

Answer (score 0):

With jquery, to change all elements of the 'item' class at the same time, you can easly do

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.item').text('MONEY');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sry, i forgot to mention that i needed a plain JS solution. No Jquery